# Web scrape - Not get any children elements

Tags: web-application, selenium-webdriver-c#, http

I have trouble in web scrape, come with short VBA for help on MSXML2.XMLHTTP60.

VBA Code's Goal: get 5 class names(num,stock-ad,data,pan-cont-chart toggle_area) from parent element(pan-cont)
URL: http://www.paxnet.co.kr/stock/analysis/main?abbrSymbol=036010

Problem:The For Loop of VBA code does not run.To run print statements in For Loop is what I want.  thanks

```
Sub post_stack()
Dim http  As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim htmldoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    http.Open "GET", "http://www.paxnet.co.kr/stock/analysis/main?abbrSymbol=036010", False
    http.send

    Do While http.Status <> 200
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
        DoEvents
    Loop
    htmldoc.Body.innerHTML = http.responseText
    
        Dim oTr As MSHTML.IHTMLElement, oTd As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
                
        Set oTr = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("pan-cont").item(0)
        Debug.Print oTr.ClassName, oTr.tagName 'Good to this line
        
        For Each oTd In oTr.Children
            Debug.Print oTd.tagName 'PROBLEM: Never RUN
        Next oTd
End Sub
```